# RequestsLibrary support parallel execute suites with pabot?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, request, robotframework

My project using **[RequestsLibrary](https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests)** to do interface automation, and all interface calls share a session, which is the session generated by the **[Create Session]** function.

On this basic, we want to do concurrency, using **[pabot](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot)**, and the way we want to use is: all multi-threads share a session for concurrency, so the [Create Session] function is currently called only once, and then all threads share the session.

The session can be retrieved from multithreads in my test , but when the interface is invoked, it is found that other thread interface requests fail：

error messages:

```
KEYWORD RequestsLibrary . Get Request ${agent.session}, ${uri}, headers=${header}, timeout=${timeout}
Documentation:  
Send a GET request on the session object found using the

Start / End / Elapsed:  20181109 15:06:36.520 / 20181109 15:06:36.523 / 00:00:00.003
15:06:36.523    FAIL    Non-existing index or alias 'adminsession'.
```

**So I would like to ask if we support concurrent scenarios?**

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] for the observed result. Right now there is quite a bit of room for interpretation that a good robot and pabot example would help clarify.

Comment: @A. Kootstra I submitted a code using request and pabot [https://github.com/Huanxin-leolil/request_pabot](https://github.com/Huanxin-leolil/request_pabot) , when I execute `pabot.bat --pabotlib --processes 2 C:\Users\leo\git\request_pabot`. One of the threads failed to execute
ERROR MESSAGE: `Non-existing index or alias 'github'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that Pabot creates parallel processes is to start multiple independent instances of Robot Framework. In each instance you'll have a separate instantiation of the RequestLibrary. As a consequence of this you'll not be able to share the same session.

Although It is possible to share values from instance to another instance through the pabotlib, this doesn't work for objects. Often an object can be serialized into a string, but sadly the Requests module that RequestsLibrary depends on doesn't support this.

In my view the best approach is to recreate identical sessions across the sessions by reusing the same cookies and other session specific variable via pabotlib.

Comment: Thanks. I think I agree with your answer. In my project, I tried to create multiple session in multithreading , and all interface use the cookie by reusing the same cookies is works perfectly in request headers.   But I need to refactor all my code,  It's more hard for me!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you matter about having the session created only once?
Pabot spawn different processes that cannot share anything directly, so what you need is to create one session for each process but basically what you want to do is just to add everything needed for your tests in a Setup Suite or Setup Test.
So that session is always available from every process and it's shared in a way that has the same configurations but is not exactly the same instance. Hope that helps.